# How to subset ID's that contain different factor values

Tags: r, subset

I'm wondering what is the best way to subset ID's that contain multiple different (factor) values.

So, lets say my data looks like this:

```
 Id <- c(1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)
 FactorValue <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1)
 data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Id,FactorValue))
 print(data)
   Id FactorValue
1  1           1
2  2           1
3  3           1
4  4           1
5  4           2
6  5           2
7  5           2
8  6           2
9  6           1
```

So as a result I would like to have ID's 4 and 6 picked since there are different factor values with the same ID. My data has over 1 million observations so I'm looking an efficient way of doing this. So far I've gotten this far, but I'm  pretty sure there is a much more efficent way of doing this:

```
a <- subset(data,data$FactorValue == 1)
b <- subset(data,data$FactorValue == 2)

ab <- rep(NA, length(data)) # vector for Id's where there are different factor values  

for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
     for (k in 1:nrow(b)) {
         if (a$Id[i] == b$Id[k]){
              ab[i] <- a$Id[i]
         }  
     }
}
print(ab)
[1] NA NA NA  4  6
```

Needless to say, it takes a while when running a for-loop with over million observations.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave`:

```
data[ave(data$FactorValue, data$Id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1, ]
#   Id FactorValue
# 4  4           1
# 5  4           2
# 8  6           2
# 9  6           1
```

Comment: +1. And a similar "data.table" approach: `DT[, N := length(unique(FactorValue)), by = Id][N > 1]`

Comment: Cheers! This is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
sort(unique(data$Id))[tapply(data$FactorValue, data$Id, 
                             function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1)]
# [1] 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data[data$Id %in% which(tapply(FactorValue, Id, function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1),]
#   Id FactorValue
# 4  4           1
# 5  4           2
# 8  6           2
# 9  6           1
```

Comment: A little explanation here would be helpful.